# How to create a simple raster in R terra

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

looking at the help file creating a raster in terra is pretty similar to raster, however, I keep getting an 'empty srs' error (for other operations in terra also).

What is srs? It seems to be the same as crs? why the name change?

```
library(raster)

d <- raster(xmn=1, xmx=17, ymn=46, ymx=57, nrows=1320, ncols = 960, vals = 1, crs = 4326)

library(terra)

d <- rast(xmin=1, xmax=17, ymin=46, ymax=57, nrows=1320, ncols = 960, vals = 1, crs = 4326)
```

Comment: Have you tried `r = terra::rast(xmin=1, xmax=17, ymin=46, ymax=57, nrows=1320, ncols = 960, vals = 1); terra::crs(r) = "epsg:4326"` or `terra::crs(r) =  "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"`?

Comment: `terra::rast(xmin=1, xmax=17, ymin=46, ymax=57, nrows=1320, ncols = 960, vals = 1, crs = "EPSG:4326")`

Comment: srs = spatial reference system; crs = coordinate reference system.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense:

```
library(terra)
# terra 1.7.71
d <- rast(crs = 4326)
# Error: [rast] empty srs
```

Because the number `4326` is not a spatial/coordinate reference system. I agree that the error message is not especially helpful.

Presumably, you want to use that EPSG code. In that case you can do

```
d <- rast(crs = "EPSG:4326")
d
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 180, 360, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)
```

You probably thought you could use `crs = 4326` because the equivalent is valid with the "sf" package. The reasons to require the ESPG prefix are that (1) it is not the only coding system (e.g. ESRI:) and (2) it much improves the readability of the code: a single number to an entry in an unspecified database is a very opaque reference.

You can also use the more descriptive PROJ notation:

```
d <- rast(crs = "+proj=longlat")
```

Comment: I think your reply illustrates why actually it makes no sense to require "espg:" in front of 4326 (what else could crs = 4326 mean?). crs = "ESPG:4326" returns the same unhelpful error ("Empty srs") as crs = 4326. Eventually after trial and error the lower case "espg:4326" seems to work.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I have expanded my answer to illustrate that this does work with the CRAN version of "terra" (for lower and upper case) and to explain the reasons for  requiring the "ESPG" prefix.

Answer (score -1):

The answer for using terra is:

```
library(terra)

d <- rast(xmin=1, xmax=17, ymin=46, ymax=57, nrows=1320, ncols = 960, vals = 1, crs = "espg:4326")
```

I would recommend using the raster package though.

Comment: Why is that? Please note that {raster} is not futher developed and has been replaced by {terra}.